USBtoSerial monitoring and modification of settings of charge controller Epever XTRA series
How can I utilize the RS485 port of Epever XTRA (and possibly also Tracer) series solar charge controller?
I'd like to use it for monitoring as well as for easy parameter modification. The system installed on my notebook is Fedora 39 at the moment.

Yes, it is possible.
The easiest way is to buy compatible USB/RS485 cable for Epever/EPsolar MPPT controllers
of XTRA/Tracer series and PWM LSxxxxB series. In my case it was marked as CC-USB-RS485-150U and lsusb reports it as:
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1a86:55d3 QinHeng Electronics USB Single Serial

# lsusb -t
/:  Bus 001.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/15p, 480M
    |__ Port 001: Dev 007, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_acm, 12M

The Fedora 39 (and probably newer) can detect it and use cdc_acm module as driver. It creates the /dev/ttyACM0 device. No special module compilation was needed in my case (there are such a projects, which can be found on the Internet - in case of older distributions or different cable models it may be required).
The charge controller I have tried the connection with is Epever XTRA4210N-XDS2.
I successfully used epevermodbus project version 0.0.18 for connection:
https://pypi.org/project/epevermodbus/0.0.18/
The installation via Python pip is really simple: pip install epevermodbus
The epevermodbus requires root privileges for running. For simple reading it is sufficient to specify the device port (/dev/ttyACM0) and slaveaddress (usually 1):
# epevermodbus --portname /dev/ttyACM0 --slaveaddress 1
Real Time Data
Solar voltage: 13.82V
Solar current: 0.47A
Solar power: 6.23W
Load voltage: 12.46V
Load current: 0.08A
Load power: 1.37W
Battery voltage: 12.46V
Battery current: 0.45A
Battery power: 6.72W
Battery state of charge: 51%
Battery temperature: 16.95°C
Remote battery temperature: 0°C
Controller temperature: 21.95°C
Battery status: {'wrong_identifaction_for_rated_voltage': False, 'battery_inner_resistence_abnormal': False, 'temperature_warning_status': 'NORMAL', 'battery_status': 'NORMAL'}
Charging equipment status: {'input_voltage_status': 'NORMAL', 'charging_mosfet_is_short_circuit': False, 'charging_or_anti_reverse_mosfet_is_open_circuit': False, 'anti_reverse_mosfet_is_short_circuit': False, 'input_over_current': False, 'load_over_current': False, 'load_short_circuit': False, 'load_mosfet_short_circuit': False, 'disequilibrium_in_three_circuits': False, 'pv_input_short_circuit': False, 'charging_status': 'BOOST', 'fault': True, 'running': True}
Discharging equipment status: {'input_voltage_status': 'NORMAL', 'output_power_load': 'LIGHT', 'short_circuit': False, 'unable_to_discharge': False, 'unable_to_stop_discharging': False, 'output_voltage_abnormal': False, 'input_over_voltage': False, 'short_circuit_in_high_voltage_side': False, 'boost_over_voltage': False, 'output_over_voltage': False, 'fault': False, 'running': True}
Day time: True
Night time: False
Maximum battery voltage today: 14.18V
Minimum battery voltage today: 12.32V
Maximum PV voltage today: 20.96V
Minimum PV voltage today: 0V
Device over temperature: False
Consumed energy today: 0.11kWh
Consumed energy this month: 0.25kWh
Consumed energy this year: 0.25kWh
Total consumed energy: 0.25kWh
Generated energy today: 0.02kWh
Generated energy this month: 0.43kWh
Generated energy this year: 0.43kWh
Total generated energy: 0.43kWh
Current device time: 2013-01-14 23:58:31


Battery Parameters:
Rated charging current: 40A
Rated load current: 40A
Battery real rated voltage: 12V
Battery type: GEL
Battery capacity: 200AH
Temperature compensation coefficient: 3mV/°C/Cell
Over voltage disconnect voltage: 16V
Charging limit voltage: 15V
Over voltage reconnect voltage: 15V
Equalize charging voltage: 15V
Boost charging voltage: 14.2V
Float charging voltage: 13.8V
Boost reconnect charging voltage: 13.2V
Low voltage reconnect voltage: 12.6V
Under voltage recover voltage: 12.2V
Under voltage warning voltage: 12V
Low voltage disconnect voltage: 11.1V
Discharging limit voltage: 10.6V
Battery rated voltage: AUTO
Default load on/off in manual mode: ON
Equalize duration: 120 min
Boost duration: 120 min
Battery discharge: 30%
Battery charge: 100%
Charging mode: VOLTAGE_COMPENSATION

Except reading in human readable form, the tool also supports export in JSON format with --json parameter. The full list of parameters is accessible with --help parameter.
There are examples of changing the date and "Equalize charging voltage" controller settings:
# epevermodbus --portname /dev/ttyACM0 --slaveaddress 1 --set-time
Old RTC value: 2013-01-15 00:03:09
New RTC value: 2024-12-14 10:51:34
# epevermodbus --portname /dev/ttyACM0 --slaveaddress 1 --set-equalize-charging-voltage 14.1
Old equalize charging voltage: 15V
New equalize charging voltage: 14.1V

To check the values really change, just read again:
# epevermodbus --portname /dev/ttyACM0 --slaveaddress 1
...
Current device time: 2024-12-14 10:55:03
...
Equalize charging voltage: 14.1V
...

With this tool you can easily modify the charging parameters to best fit your battery settings - doing so through the controller monitoring LCD is quite a nightmare...
(Low values explanation - this installation is quite small (400Wp) and in winter cloudy conditions of the day and mostly SW orientation it does not generate much power - when it is sunny, the energy production is much better - later that day it was producing some 40W and still it wasn't really sunny.)
